# Is it possible to use WebDriverWait to wait until no elements match an XPath expression?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to writing unit tests. I looked at the Python Selenium docs and there's a [list of conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) that are supported. I came across an example code snippet that implemented a custom condition like this:

```
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5, poll_frequency=0.1)
server_list = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                             '//div[@class="server_name"]'))
```

Is it possible to do the reverse of this in a similar way? I'd like it to wait until this condition doesn't match.

At present I'm waiting until the `WebElement` is stale.

Example:

```
for server in server_list:
    wait.until(expected_conditions.staleness_of(s))
```

This makes it slow when there are multiple elements to wait on sequentially. Is there a better way?

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait

until_not works this way

Comment: You should be able to write a custom wait that waits for the count of elements to be 0. Have you tried googling this? What did you find? What else have you tried?

Comment: @RonNorris, that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

`wait.until_not(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                             '//div[@class="server_name"]'))`